# What's the simplest way to encoding List<String> into plain String and decode it back?

Tags: c#, serialization

I think I've come across this requirement for a dozen times. But I could never find a satisfying solution. For instance, there are a collection of string which I want to serialize (to disk or through network) through a channel where only plain string is allowed.
I almost always end up using "split" and "join" with ridiculous separator like

> ":::==--==:::".

like this:

```
public static string encode(System.Collections.Generic.List<string> data)
{
    return string.Join(" :::==--==::: ", data.ToArray());
}
public static string[] decode(string encoded)
{
    return encoded.Split(new string[] { " :::==--==::: " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

But this simple solution apparently has some flaws.  The string cannot contains the separator string.  And consequently, the encoded string can no longer re-encoded again.

AFAIK, the comprehensive solution should involve escaping the separator on encoding and unescaping on decoding.  While the problem sound simple, I believe the complete solution can take significant amount of code.  I wonder if there is any trick allowed me to build encoder & decoder in very few lines of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this manually. As the other answers have pointed out, there are plenty of ways, built-in or otherwise, to serialize/deserialize.

However, if you did decide to do the work yourself, it doesn't require *that* much code:

```
public static string CreateDelimitedString(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        sb.Append(item.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace(",", "\\,"));
        sb.Append(",");
    }

    return (sb.Length > 0) ? sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1) : string.Empty;
}
```

This will delimit the items with a comma (`,`). Any existing commas will be escaped with a backslash (`\`) and any existing backslashes will also be escaped.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetItemsFromDelimitedString(string s)
{
    bool escaped = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if ((c == '\\') && !escaped)
        {
            escaped = true;
        }
        else if ((c == ',') && !escaped)
        {
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Length = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            escaped = false;
        }
    }

    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Sake, I didn't knock it up instantly, although it didn't take too long. (I actually wrote it a few days ago as a response to a different SO question.)

Comment: @Luke, But you'd prefer Earwicker solution ? Why ?

Comment: @Sake, As I said at the top of my answer, you shouldn't need to serialize/deserialize manually these days. URL encoding is tried-and-tested and (mostly) human-readable. And in most modern languages/frameworks it only takes a line or two of code.

Comment: I think it's possible to do this much simpler.  Just replace one character (like `|` with `|s`).  Then use `||` as separator.  When splitting, just split on any `||` found.  After that unescape the split strings by replacing `|s` with `|`.

Answer (score 6):

Add a reference and `using` to System.Web, and then:

```
public static string Encode(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return string.Join("&", strings.Select(s => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s)).ToArray());
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Decode(string list)
{
    return list.Split('&').Select(s => HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s));
}
```

Most languages have a pair of utility functions that do Url "percent" encoding, and this is ideal for reuse in this kind of situation.

Comment: Mmmm, I could forgive someone for reinventing the wheel maybe, but reinventing string escaping is beyond the pale!

Comment: Voted. BTW, the UrlEncode is absolutely not my favorite solution. It'd encode my native character into %NN.

Comment: Thanks. It sure would, but it depends what you want. If you want a human readable data stream for some specific set of characters, you have to write your own encode/decode. If you want a quick solution and don't care how the stream looks, use URL encoding.

Comment: plus one - simpler than the xml variant I did

Answer (score 5):

You could use the .ToArray property on the List<> and then serialize the Array - that could then be dumped to disk or network, and reconstituted with a deserialization on the other end.

Not too much code, and you get to use the serialization techniques already tested and coded in the .net framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, the channel can only allowed "string". And I always want the output to be "readable".

Comment: .Net serialization will go to strings.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to look at the way CSV files are formatted.

- escape all instances of a deliminater, e.g. " in the string
- wrap each item in the list in "item"
- join using a simple seperator like ,

I don't believe there is a silver bullet solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an old-school technique that might be suitable -

Serialise by storing the width of each string[] as a fixed-width prefix in each line.

So

```
 string[0]="abc"
 string[1]="defg"
 string[2]=" :::==--==::: "
```

becomes

```
0003abc0004defg0014 :::==--==:::
```

...where the size of the prefix is large enough to cater for the string maximum length

Comment: Why I couldn't come out with this solution before ! Nice solution !

Comment: I like this one, you could modify it slightly to be the size plus a separator so you can handle any size prefix, for example: 3|abc4|defg6|--==--

Comment: You could add another separator after the string as well even though it's not required for parsing, just to make it easier to read. Something like 3`abc`4`defg`6`--==-- or 3:abc:4:defg:6:--==-- . That last one is starting to look like the php serialize() function :) a:1:{s:5:"Hello";s:5:"World";}

Answer (score 2):

You could use an XmlDocument to handle the serialization.  That will handle the encoding for you.

```
public static string encode(System.Collections.Generic.List<string> data)
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("data"));
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var xmlItem = (XmlElement)xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("item"));
        xmlItem.InnerText = item;
    }
    return xml.OuterXml;
}

public static string[] decode(string encoded)
{
    var items = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(encoded);
    foreach (XmlElement xmlItem in xml.SelectNodes("/data/item"))
        items.Add(xmlItem.InnerText);
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I sometimes do exactly what you suggest. But it's overkill in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

I would just prefix every string with its length and an terminator indicating the end of the length.

```
abc
defg
hijk
xyz
546
4.X
```

becomes

**3:** abc **4:** defg **4:** hijk **3:** xyz **3:** 546 **3:** 4.X

No restriction or limitations at all and quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) is a very easy way to serialize about any object you can imagine. JSON keeps things compact and can be faster than XML.

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
List<string> fooToo = (List<string>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output, typeof(List<string>));
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done much simpler if you are willing to use a separator of 2 characters long:

In java code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
for(String s : list) {
  if(builder.length() != 0) {
    builder.append("||");
  }
  builder.append(s.replace("|", "|p"));
}
```

And back:

```
for(String item : encodedList.split("||")) {
  list.add(item.replace("|p", "|"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialise it, rather than reinventing your own serialisation format?

Its pretty simple:

```
new XStream().toXML(yourobject)
```

Comment: That's fine. The question is language agnostic. I'd personally prefer python answer. My sample is in C# to attract more audiences.

Answer (score 0):

Include the **System.Linq** library in your file and change your functions to this:

```
    public static string encode(System.Collections.Generic.List<string> data, out string delimiter)
    {
        delimiter = ":";
        while(data.Contains(delimiter)) delimiter += ":";
        return string.Join(delimiter, data.ToArray());
    }
    public static string[] decode(string encoded, string delimiter)
    {
        return encoded.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
```

Comment: So the delimiter will have to be embedded along with the message ?

Comment: Yes, u include it with the message so it can be decoded.  It solves both your problems you mentioned.

Comment: What if the end of one of the strings contains the delimiter, for example: "abc:def" or even just "abc:"?

Comment: The while statement checks if the string contains the delimiter and modifies it until it is not found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of textual markup languages out there, any would *function*

Many would function trivially given the simplicity of your input it all depends on how:

1. human readable you want the encoding
2. resilient to api changes it should be
3. how easy to parse it is
4. how easy it is to write or get a parser for it.

If the last one is the most important then just use the existing xml libraries MS supply for you:

```
class TrivialStringEncoder
{
    private readonly XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));

    public string Encode(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        using (var s = new StringWriter())
        {
            ser.Serialize(s, input.ToArray());
            return s.ToString();
        }       
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Decode(string input)
    {
        using (var s = new StringReader(input))
        {
            return (string[])ser.Deserialize(s);            
        }       
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var encoded = Encode(args);
        Console.WriteLine(encoded);
        var decoded = Decode(encoded);
        foreach(var x in decoded)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

running on the inputs "A", "<", ">" you get (edited for formatting):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>A</string>
  <string>&lt;</string>
  <string>&gt;</string>
</ArrayOfString>
A
<
>
```

Verbose, slow but *extremely* simple and requires no additional libraries